# Why is .append() screwing up my <option> elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got an issue with this code :

```
$(function(){
    function typeHTML() {
                var types = ['text', 'image', 'select'];
                var result = '<select>';
                for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
                    result += '<option value="' + types[i] + '">' + types[i] + '</option>';
                }
                result += '</select>';
                return result;
            }
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            $('#my-table').append('<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td><input type="text" value="' + i + '"/></td><td>' + typeHTML() + '</td><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input type="text"/>,<input type="text"/></td></tr>');
}
});
```

See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/D659E/

You can see that typeHTML() is a function that builds a  element with types[i] as the inner text of each option. But when I append it, the HTML comes out as:

```
<select>
    <option value="text"></option>
    text
    <option value="image"></option>
    image
    <option value="select"></option>
    select
</select>
```

where the `types[i]`that was supposed to be the inner text of an option, is instead moved outside the option. Why is this happening? When I log the HTML being appended, it looks correct, so it appears this issue occurs in the `append()` call itself. I am using jQuery 1.9.1.

Comment: because of this `'"/>'` (6th line in the fiddle) you're *self-closing* the element.

Comment: That is not valid HTML.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar The question is why it ends up like this.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, read the question

Comment: @Yoshi is right:  http://jsfiddle.net/D659E/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the option two times :

```
result += '<option value="' + types[i] + '"/>' + types[i] + '</option>';
```

So, change this to

```
result += '<option value="' + types[i] + '">' + types[i] + '</option>';
```

Comment: Ah, who put that slash there? =) Thanks!